# Comparing values in a dictionary to values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

Basically, the program checks if the rhyming pattern of a poem is correct. I've taken the parameter of ['A', 'B', 'A'] and arranged it in a dictionary that has the index of words to compare.

```
rhyme_pattern = {'A': [0, 2], 'B': [1]}
```

I've also taken the last word from each line and put that into a list.

```
words_to_compare = ['OFF', 'NEXT', 'ENDS']
```

And I've made a helper function that compares two words and if they rhyme. I can't figure out how to loop through rhyme_pattern['A'] and compare the words 'OFF' and 'ENDS'. Also, I then get the problem of not comparing anything if there is only one index value, like B.

Comment: show your code please, input, desired output.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict.get(some_val, [])` to ensure that an empty list is returned if `some_val` doesn't appear in the `dict`:

```
rhyme_pattern.get('A', [])
```

and then write your helper function so that it behaves as expected when an entry has just the empty list.

Assuming your comparison function is called `compare_with`, then you can compare with the elements in `dict['A']` like this:

```
[compare_with(x, y) for x in rhyme_pattern.get('A', []) 
                    for y in words_to_compare]
```

This last bit assumes your comparison function works like `compare_with(0, 'OFF')`. If instead you are looking to index into `words_to_compare` via the contents of `rhyme_pattern['A']`, it might look like this:

```
A_words = [word_to_compare[x] for x in rhyme_pattern.get('A', [])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rhyme_pattern = {'A': [0, 2], 'B': [1]}
words_to_compare = ['OFF', 'NEXT', 'ENDS']
for val in rhyme_pattern["A"]:
    print(words_to_compare[val])
```

To access all values iterate over the values:

```
for val in rhyme_pattern.itervalues(): # just .values() for python 3
    print([words_to_compare[v] for v in val])
```

This presumes that all the values will be in the index range of  words_to_compare  which from your question seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through rhyme_pattern and compare all values in any array with more than 1 value. The hard part is getting all combinations of words to compare. the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) library makes this easy.

This should work:

```
import itertools as it  
for words in rhyme_pattern:
        if len(words) > 1:
             #now loop through all combinations of 2 words
             for pair in it.permutations(words,2):
                 if not words_ryhme(*pair):
                    return False
return True
```